# Unable to load library 'cxcore': libcxcore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu

When I run project jar file, it gives following error message

```
Exception in cameracheck Thread - check();java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'cxcore': libcxcore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CameraProperties.CheckForCameraPlugin.check(CheckForCameraPlugin.java:55)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

> Thanks Haris. You spend much time with me. Thanks a lot. The issue has
>   been sorted out. I provided 2 commands inside /usr/local/lib. 1) sudo
>   ln -s libopencv_core.so.2.4.6 libcxcore.so 2) sudo ln -s
>   libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.6 libhighgui.so. In another computer with
>   2.3.1 version of opencv, I provided the same commands with corresponding version number under /usr/lib. Thanks again. I am so
>   happy. :) :) :)

Comment: See similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212728/libcxcore-so-2-missing-in-opencv

Comment: In order to create symbolic link, I can't find that .so file in my computer.

Comment: You may need to installing libcv, libcvaux, libhighgui and their -dev libraries from Synaptics

Comment: Thanks Haris, I double checked all those packages from Synaptics. All are installed. Still not seeing that libcxcore.so under /usr/lib

Comment: Just check in /usr/local/opencv/lib

Comment: Such a folder is not there Haris. I am using Ubuntu. I checked inside /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib with no luck.

Comment: So how did you installed OpenCV ?

Comment: "pkg-config --modversion opencv" says that 2.3.1. So I confirmed it's installed.

Comment: Just check this pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv

Comment: I executed that command and received following result

Comment: -I/usr/include/opencv  -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann

Comment: One more time check libopencv-dev is installed

Comment: Yes Haris,in Synaptics package manager it's showing as installed.

Comment: Just tried the steps as mentioned in below URL

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/334158/installing-opencv

Comment: Now the version is 2.4.6.1

Comment: Thanks Haris. You spend much time with me. Thanks a lot. The issue has been sorted out. I provided 2 commands inside /usr/local/lib. 1) sudo ln -s libopencv_core.so.2.4.6 libcxcore.so 2) sudo ln -s libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.6 libhighgui.so. In another computer with 2.3.1 version of opencv, I provided the same commands with corresponding version number under /usr/lib. Thanks again. I am so happy. :) :) :)